# ASP.NET Browser not deleting cookie even after expiring

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I expired a cookie by setting `Expires` property to a past date and I can see in Fiddler that it worked. But,

1. I don't see the change updated in Firefox cookie window. I tried closing cookie and Firefox window, but no luck.
2. When I make another request to the same page (same domain), those cookies come back again

Now I know that it is up to the browser to delete cookies when it likes, but I thought it will be before the user hits the same website again.

How do I make sure browser deletes them before next request comes in from that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to successfully delete a cookie, not only do you need to set an `Expires` date in the past, you also need to specify the same `path` and `domain` properties that you used when you first set the cookie. Those properties are not sent to the server with each request, so you have to keep track of them in some other way.

The reason for this is that you can have two cookies with the same name, but with different `path` or `domain` properties, so the browser needs all of the details to know which one to delete.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Expires` property of a cookie you are basically setting a persistent cookie. This means that this cookie is no longer stored in the memory of the browser but it is saved on the client computer and it will survive browser and even computer restarts until the specified date is reached. If you don't set the `Expires` property, you are creating a non-persistent cookie which will only be valid until the user closes the browser (closong the current tab will pertain the cookie value and if the user opens a new tab and visits your site again, the cookie will be send again and there's nothing you could do about it). There's no notion of a cookie per tab/window in the HTTP protocol specification which obviously is normal as there is no notion of a browser *tab* or a *window* in this specification.

To learn more about cookies take a look at the [following article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) which covers the different types.